# How to have an instance object available to all tests?

Tags: go, testing

I am writing component tests for an http service. I have a test runner class that houses some helpful structs and shared functions (mostly just "make an http call" and "compare json structures"). This test runner class will need to have the domain to send the http calls to, pulled from envvars. Rather than fetching the domain from the envvars every time I make an http call, I would prefer to parse it once and set it in an instance of the test runner class, and then have this instance be available to all of my test functions.

Given that the expected signature of a test function is `func TestXxx(t *testing.T) {...}` how can I make this instance available to my tests?

Code:

- [main.go](https://github.com/rosemaryehlers/habits/blob/backend/backend/testsv2/main.go) - using TestMain to fetch the domain from envvars and create instance of test runner class
- [testrunner.go](https://github.com/rosemaryehlers/habits/blob/backend/backend/testsv2/testrunner/testrunner.go) - helper class to make http calls and validating results easier
- [tests.go](https://github.com/rosemaryehlers/habits/blob/backend/backend/testsv2/views/tests.go) - actual tests being run. I am in the process of converting them to use golang's testing library, but you can see currently they require a parameter (the test runner instance)

Comment: What problems have you faced while using `func TestMain(m *testing.M) { ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a package-level variable to store the value.  Initialize the value in an accessor function. Use sync.Once to ensure the initialization is done once.

```
type Helper struct {
    message string
}

var (
    helper     *Helper
    helperOnce sync.Once
)

func getHelper() *Helper {
    helperOnce.Do(func() {
        helper = &Helper{"Hello"}
    })
    return helper
}

func TestFirst(t *testing.T) {
    h := getHelper()
    t.Log(h.message)
}

func TestSecond(t *testing.T) {
    h := getHelper()
    t.Log(h.message)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/gogalnqq0UX